# Can anyone explain what this line of code means and what I should do with it?

Tags: python, parameters, namespaces

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

i = int(input().strip())

f = float(input().strip())

s = input()

b = input().strip()

Assign(i, f, s, b)
```

I've been given a challenge:
Write the function definition for the function 'Assign' the different types of variable in it's parameters to new variables.

What does " if **name** == '**main**': "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 1):

i - gets input from the user and make it an int. then use strip to remove spaces

f - gets input from the user and make it a float. then use strip to remove spaces

s - gets input from the user

b - gets input from the user and then use strip to remove spaces

here is some reference for if name == 'main' [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)